# IronPython Websockets

Tags: ironpython

How can I implement websockets in ironpython?

Ironpython seems to only support sockets with INET headers (IPv4).

I require to connect through the host url wss://echo.websocket.org.

```
#socket
import socket
host = "wss://echo.websocket.org"
port = 8000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.connect((host,port))
    s.send("Hello World")
finally:
    s.close()

print s
```

When I try to connect, it gives an:

```
 [Errno 11001] no addresses of the specified family associated with host
```

Is there a better way to approach this? For example importing an external library that deals specifically with websockets?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem (I'm using the ObsWebsocket to control obs from python), I have tried to use the websocket and I get a similar error: [Errno 10044] The support for the specified socket type does not exist in this address family
Finally, I found a workaround. I'm using Subprocess to handle all the IronPython stuff and using a Python 3 Script to execute the communication via socket

I send you a piece of my code. I hope that it helps:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

creturn_code = Popen("ipy IronPythonScript.py", shell=True, stdout = PIPE) #You can change the ipy for py and use an similar code in IronPython
rrline = creturn_code.stdout.readline() #This read the stdout of the script

rline = str(rrline)[2: (len(rrline))] #This remove the fking b'' that is always (i dont know why)

if(rline != ""): #Check that the output of the another process realy contains something
```

Here you can implement all that you need to

I'm using this on Python3 and it works. IronPython is handling all the dlls things and python3 is handling all the communications

If my English is not perfect excuse me, I'm from Argentina